Go - os.UserHomeDir() returning " C:\Users\<user_name>" on WSL
I'm learning and trying out golang to create an application that needs access to user home directory.
To make easier to understand the problem, consider this main.go:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    home, err := os.UserHomeDir()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Err: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("HOME: %s\n", home)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}


After building the application I tried to run it on windows and macos and the output worked well.
For linux, I tried to run on WSL, I don't know if that's the problem
HOME: C:\Users\<user>

On wsl I've tried to echo $HOME and it showed the correct homedir.
Also to get os.Getenv("HOME") and was printing empty
Also tried to PrintAll envs and there was no HOME environment variable. Actually, there was no linux environment variable, only windows

Update

To build the application I'm using the following command on my windows machine

go build -o C:/_builds/.bin/example .


Then I navigate to this folder using according to the windows mount in wsl.

 cd /mnt/c/_builds/.bin

And run the command
./example

Here is the output terminal


I've ommited my machine information and username

Do you have any ideas? Am I missing something?

Can you detail how exactly you're executing the application (i.e. share the command you're running)?

Also, your example program discards the error returns by os.UserHomeDir(). (The error message will let you know what OS the binary was built for.) Try this instead: https://go.dev/play/p/NW30nn4_oJI

@chuckx that error isn’t discarded but checked in the provided code

I've updated the code here and also the commands that I use to build and run the application. But the main goal is not to think about the logic here, it's just a simple example to show what is happening.

(Note: In a previous revision, the error was being stored in the message variable before calling os.Exit(1), essentially discarding it.) Now that the error is being printed, what is the error?

No errors, It just print HOME: C:\Users\<my_windows_username>.  I'll attach an image in the post to show.

FYI, my confusion stemmed from the title stating that the return value was "" vs the actual return value being C:\Users\<my_windows_username>.

I'll fix the question title, I was writing down and forgot to fix it

You're building a Windows binary.
When you execute it in the WSL environment, it's still a Windows binary, still retains the runtime.GOOS value set at compile time, and will still trigger the Windows specific code path in the os.UserHomeDir() implementation.

To build a Linux binary, try setting the GOOS environment variable before running the go build command. Something like:
set GOOS="linux"
go build -o C:/_builds/.bin/example_linux .

The full set of environment variables that influence operation of the go command are documented at https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Environment_variables.

For background on WSL supporting execution of Windows executables see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems#run-windows-tools-from-linux.

Many thanks, I actually saw something related to it and a missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.
